# How to know the menu ID

Tags: 8, navigation

Like a function to debug a page or something. Want to add a link via links.yml but can't get the menu 'parent' name
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `hook_menu_local_tasks()` or `hook_menu_local_task()`. It is primary Tabs.

```
function mymodule_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {
  foreach ($data['tabs'] as $key1 => $tabs) {
    foreach ($tabs['output'] as $key2 => $item) {
      // Conditionally change the link title.
      if ($item['#link']['path'] == 'some/path/here') {
        $data['tabs'][$key1]['output'][$key2]['#link']['title'] = 'New Title';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting is the *route name*, not menu parent name (it's changed since D7). You can retrieve a route name a couple of different ways:

- Use [`Url::getRouteName()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AgetRouteName/8.6.x) to look up your current route:

  `$path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();`
  `$url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri( 'internal:' . $path );`
  `$url->getRouteName()`
- Use the [Webprofiler](https://www.drupal.org/project/webprofiler) module to look up the current route as you're viewing it.
- Look up URL patterns in the `router` DB table.

To see how the core node module does it for the tasks in your screenshot look at [`core/modules/node/node.links.task.yml`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.links.task.yml/8.6.x)

For further information on adding local tasks to routes, read [*Providing module-defined local tasks*](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/menu-api/providing-module-defined-local-tasks).